# Format number n SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to format the number like this:

From `65803.12345` to `65803.12`.

From `65803.98500` to `65803.98`.

Comment: Use `CAST(Num AS DECIMAL(18,2))`

Comment: Do you want to round or truncate? Add 65803.12666 to your sample data!

Comment: Also consider doing this in the front-end application instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only two digits after decimal point without ceiling or floor.

```
DECLARE @i AS float 
DECLARE @TmpInt AS INT 
DECLARE @TmpDec AS FLOAT 

SELECT @i = 65803.12345 
SELECT @TmpInt = (SELECT CAST(@i AS INT))
SELECT @TmpDec = @i - @TmpInt
SELECT CAST(((CAST(@TmpInt AS VARCHAR(50)) + SUBSTRING((LEFT((CAST(@TmpDec AS VARCHAR(50))), 4)), 2, 3))) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
-- Output : 65803.12

SELECT @i = 65803.98500
SELECT @TmpInt = (SELECT CAST(@i AS INT))
SELECT @TmpDec = @i - @TmpInt
SELECT CAST(((CAST(@TmpInt AS VARCHAR(50)) + SUBSTRING((LEFT((CAST(@TmpDec AS VARCHAR(50))), 4)), 2, 3))) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
-- Output : 65803.98

SELECT @i = 65803.12666
SELECT @TmpInt = (SELECT CAST(@i AS INT))
SELECT @TmpDec = @i - @TmpInt
SELECT CAST(((CAST(@TmpInt AS VARCHAR(50)) + SUBSTRING((LEFT((CAST(@TmpDec AS VARCHAR(50))), 4)), 2, 3))) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
-- Output : 65803.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROUND(,)`:

```
ROUND(column, decimals)
```

More info: [W3Schools detailed information](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 declare @s decimal(12,5)
 set @s = 65803.98500
 select cast(@s-@s%1+cast(@s%1*100 as int)*0.01 as decimal(12,2))
```

Result is

```
65803.98
```